# Content length is always negative

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I don't know but content length is always negative even if repsonse has corrent Content-Length header. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string result = Get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            Console.WriteLine("Response length = {0}", result.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static string Get(string adr)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(adr);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0";
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.Timeout = 10000;
        req.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
        req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 10;
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;


        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Response stream is nulL!");
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Content length = {0}", response.ContentLength);
                    return WebUtility.HtmlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fiddler shows following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 20:36:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Cf-Railgun: fe8c0e42fd 44.42 0.042796 0030 3350
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: bc3ccb1f-1de5-4375-b30d-f3c89134cf86
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 21fc0233f6652bca-AMS
Content-Length: 251540
```

But in program I get this:

[image]

how can it be fixed?

Comment: 1) When content-lenght is not present in the server response it will be -1 as per Httpresponse.ContentLenght on MSDN 2) Fiddler probably used a method similar to yours to get an actual count but you get 240427 vs 251540 because the response is UTF-8 while .Net strings are UTF-16. Such things would throw off string.lenght in your Main()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things:

When I try, stackoverflow.com does not set a Content-Length header, so it will come through as -1.

But, changing the URL to use a server which definitely does set a Content-Length header, e.g., www.theguardian.com, still produces the same result: -1.

I think it's your use of `AutomaticDecompression` on the `HttpWebRequest` object.

If you don't set that property the ContentLength property comes through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This means that it is Fiddler that is returning the content-length.  The reason that Fiddler would do that is that you have the 'Stream' button pressed (or some otherway to indicate to fiddler you want to return 'Stream' or 'Chunked' data.

When a server returns 'Chunked' data, it sets the content-length to -1 -- you don't know the length of the content since you can have unlimited chunks.

If you unclick (or turn off) streaming, then fiddler returns its default 'buffered' response, which is an exact copy of the response from the server.  Which of course will include that Content-Length header.

Literally just went through this -- HTH!