# How to Know the content length of the response body without using response.getBody() or Content-length header parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-headers, resttemplate

I have a class called `GenericServiceImpl` that execute`restTemplateGeneric.exchange()` method ( where `restTemplateGeneric` is an `RestTemplate` object) and 
other class called `ServiceApiInterceptor` that extend from `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

the configuration of `restTemplate` is like follow:

```java
public RestTemplate restTemplateGeneric() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> chri = new ArrayList<>();
        chri.add(new RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor());
        chri.add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(this.parameterConfigApi.getSecurementUsername(),
                this.parameterConfigApi.getSecurementPassword()));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(chri);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(getComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()));
        return restTemplate;
    }

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {
            return super.exHttpComponentsClientRequestFactory(parameterConfigApi);
    }
```

The `ServiceApiInterceptor` class's objective is intercept the request(`PUT`, `DELETE`, `POST`, `GET`), in order to log the information of the request and the response.

```java
    private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = response.getHeaders();
        long longitud = httpHeaders.getContentLength();

        System.out.println("LONGITUD DEL CONTENIDO DEL RESPONSE..........:"+longitud);

        try (
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getBody(), DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        ){
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                inputStringBuilder.append(line);
                inputStringBuilder.append(NEXT_LINE);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error reading service response", e);
        }

        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        logBuilder.append(RESPONSE_LAYER).append(NEXT_LINE);
        logBuilder.append(STATUS_CODE_LAYER).append(response.getStatusCode()).append(NEXT_LINE);
        logBuilder.append(STATUS_TEXT_LAYER).append(response.getStatusText()).append(NEXT_LINE);
        logBuilder.append(HEADERS_LAYER).append(response.getHeaders()).append(NEXT_LINE);
        logBuilder.append(RESPONSE_BODY_LAYER).append(inputStringBuilder.toString()).append(NEXT_LINE);
        logBuilder.append(SEPARATOR);

        log.info(logBuilder.toString());
    }
```

The problem is when I execute a `PUT` request, the response body don't return nothing, I mean the body is not `null` but there is nothing to read. For this situation when I try to read the response body in order to show in the log, the code throw and `EOFException`. I deep into the method `reponse.getBody()` of `ClientHttpResponse` object and this occure because the body don't have a content to read, I mean, the body is not null but is empty, there is nothing to read.

the  `throwed` error is from the class `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` when start to read de body, that is an `InputStream` object.

```java
/*
     * Reads unsigned byte.
     */
    private int readUByte(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int b = in.read();
        if (b == -1) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        if (b < -1 || b > 255) {
            // Report on this.in, not argument in; see read{Header, Trailer}.
            throw new IOException(this.in.getClass().getName()
                + ".read() returned value out of range -1..255: " + b);
        }
        return b;
    }
```

The other problem is that the header's response has configured to transfer the information encoding , when I review the header of the response I can see the following configuration:

`Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]`

bacause of that, the `content-length` parameter of the response's header always return -1:
(I do a research and I find this link about this response [Content length is always negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362664/content-length-is-always-negative))

the first request is a `GET` and the second is a `POST` request

```
[13/02/20 19:00:05:484 COT] 00000111 SystemOut     O LONGITUD DEL CONTENIDO DEL REQUEST..........:0
[13/02/20 19:00:06:125 COT] 00000111 SystemOut     O LONGITUD DEL CONTENIDO DEL RESPONSE..........:-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13/02/20 19:00:06:188 COT] 00000111 SystemOut     O LONGITUD DEL CONTENIDO DEL REQUEST..........:179
[13/02/20 19:00:06:880 COT] 00000111 SystemOut     O LONGITUD DEL CONTENIDO DEL RESPONSE..........:-1
```

I really gratefull if you could help me to find out another way to know the length of the content body without using `content-length` header's parameter and the `response.getBody()` method.